# On the molecular level, how do catalysts work?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, catalysis

I already know what catalysts do (lower activation energy requirement for a reaction), but how exactly are they able to do that on a molecular level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general terms, some catalysts serve as a "meeting place" where the reacting species can get together more easily, e.g. $\ce{H2}$ and $\ce{O2}$ adsorbed onto a $\ce{Pt}$ catalyst; see [this](https://www.chem.umn.edu/services/lecturedemo/info/Hydrogen_and_Platinum.html).

Others may actually participate in a reaction but are regenerated afterwards, e.g. according to [Maggs and Sutton](http://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/1958/tf/tf9585401861), "argentous hydroperoxide" is produced as an intermediate in the catalytic decomposition of $\ce{H2O2}$ by $\ce{Ag}$, and regenerates the silver ions as it decomposes.